# An Array in which 3 objects represent one Cell in uitableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I'm loading data from sql into an NSMutableArray lets say its a table of Entries of Height and Weight each having a timeStamp (NSDate)

So the User enters the height and Weight!

I make  a call to the entries to fetch all data sorted by timeStamp, that is the latest is the first.

this is the order i get,

-Height - 30 Jan 2012
-Weight - 30 Jan 2012

-Height - 30 December 2011
-Weight - 30 December 2011

-Height - Novem 2011
-Weight - Novem 2011

So i have 6 objects in my mutableArray.

ALthought in the tableView datasource, I want only 3 rows. Each with the combination of ht/wt.

So what Would be my function in cellforRow/numberOfRows/ and again retrieving these combos in didSelectRow.

2-Also, in the above Example the each row has 2 objects, What if there was another situation where i'd require 3 objects. 
For example, Systolic Blood Pressure/Diastolic Blood Pressure/ Pulse pressure all entered by the user and retrieved in sorted timestamps,
IN this case each row will have 3 objects represented, and 3 rows will have 9 in total..

The number of objects represented in each row will be predefined before I call for entries, So i would know the number of objects each cell is going to have... just don't know how to go about it..

thanks for your help!

[EDIT:] I'll clear up one thing, that the Entries table - has its own Entryobject class
Each class has an-
-Value
-Timestamp
-CategoryID

The reason i don't want to have an Object defined for height/weight is because:
- height and weight are not returned in  a single row.. it depends on the combination of category for example BodyMassIndex category will return a combo of 2 entries as explained above, So id have to compute here again, .. which defeats the purpose of the object itself.

- Other reason being that i cannot define it, i wouldn't  know if an entry is SBP, Ht or wt.  Its what the CategoryObject would call,  lets say for Ht entry and Wt entry, both have an CategoryID as 1. SBP, DP, PP will have a CategoryID as 2.

This way is for making the app more scalable for the future! though its taking me down!

Amm, got a solution using mAtH!! will this be super expensive on memory?

fieldCount is number of properties. ht and wt  = 2!

```
    limiterIndex=indexPath.row * fieldCount;

    NSMutableArray *returnArray = [NSMutableArray new];

    for(int i=limiterIndex; i<(limiterIndex+fieldCount); i++){ 
    [returnArray addObject:[entriesArray objectAtIndex:i]; 
    } 
    [cell setDataFromArray:returnArray];
    [returnArray release];
```

Im not sure this will work, but it does seem to get the entries per cell from the all in one entries array!, at least on paper!

Seems like an expensive way to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

You should make a custom object that holds every data you need in a single cell. Then put those in an array and use it as it's datasource.

In your case put the width and height data in some myObject. Then put those myObjects in an myObjectsArray and use that as its datasource.

Then in your cells extract a myObject and extract from those the height and width.

This you can use to fill the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

This u can use for the dimensions of the cell in the heightForRowAtIndexpath:

Of course you can do this for other data as well. Just make a custom object which contains the data for you table.

So in short, I suggest making those custom objects and use those as the tableView's datasource.
You will figure it out.
Good luck.

Comment: Hey, yes, your right, Ideally a custom object that holds both ht/wt is should be used.

But this was just an example of many other similar situations where maybe the object per cell is just one or two (in ht/wt) or 3 in (sBP/DBP/PP)

And each entry the user names is received in an object that has Value,TimeStamp,Category.  and it comes in this Entry Object class. THe thing is I don't want to define the object i retrieve as entry, it could be an entry about anything else. not just ht/wt. Just depends on what Im calling from the category table. 
Maybe i'd somehow ID add/divide entries ->nsdict?

Comment: Well you should use that custom object but you also will have to identify them somehow. If it doesnt matter what data de object holds you might want to use an array where u put in all the data then put that array in your datasource. so when you call the object in the data source it returns you an array which then can be used to display its contents whichever they might be. Understand?:)

Comment: Hmm, lets say the combined data from sql is now in entriesArray.
Data in it is in the form of - (1)Ht-Entry, (2)Wt-Entry, (3)Ht-Entry, (4)Wt-Entry. For each indexPath i need those two entries..

Comment: Damn, i  just freakin created a formula in CellForIndexPath. int entryIndex; First i multiply indexPath.row with FieldCount which is a count of properties. like ht and wt so FieldCount = 2. limiterIndex=indexPath.row * fieldCount;
NSMutableArray *returnArray = [NSMutableArray new];
for(int i=limiterIndex; i<(limiterIndex+fieldCount); i++){ [returnArray addObject:[entriesArray objectAtIndex:i]; }
Now i have returnArray with those two ht/wt combo in one cell!! is this super expensive on memory? I added this to the edited answer

Answer (score 0):

I would create a model object that retrieves the master array of all entries.

This model object would also have methods that return the correct data based upon the index passed.

```
 weightString = (NSString*)[self.dataModel getWeightAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

I would then create the cells dynamically by adding text/field views to the cells as needed.

EDIT:

If you want a method that can vary in what it returns create one like :

```
weightString = (NSString*)[self.dataModel getDataAtIndex:indexPath.row forDataType:@"weight"];
```

Comment: Could you please expand, I'm sorta getting it. But you see, any custom object i create, would have methods like 'getWeightAtIndex' etc, but what if the entry was about a blood pressure reading? pulse pressure? height? it could be anything..